# Ball of Light (Light, Material?) glutsolidsphere

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, lighting

I'm programming a game which is called Falldown. I'm almost finished; now I want to design the ball. How can I light this ball such that it glows like these examples?

[image]

[image]

I created my cube with glutSolidSphere and ask myself how I can light the ball.

```
void ball()
{
    glColor4f(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5);
    glutSolidSphere(0.25,40,40);        
}

void initLightSources()
{
     ?????? 

     glEnable( GL_LIGHTING );
     glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
     glEnable( GL_LIGHT0 );
}
```

Comment: One of your sample pictures shows just a glow over a sphere while another shows some additional features. Do you want to get just a glow or something more?

Comment: I like the 2nd example more, but i think it will be more difficult.?

Comment: I think he wants to achieve the glowing effect.

Comment: Yes, that could be. I´ve already heard about it.

Comment: Well here you go then, Google -> "glowing effect openGL". Usually it's done as a post rendering effect so your won't be able to do it as simply as `glEnable(GL_KICKASS_GLOWING_EFFECT);`

Comment: I wish it would be that easy, but there are no entries about the glowing effect in combination to a sphere. Sry, but I´m still a beginner in programming.